# l already install idea2019.1 then want to install idea 2022.2.3,but can't open,it shows

Tags: intellij-idea

I have tried reinstalling and restarting the computer. Modified the script and went with a higher version of jdk.
[终端报错信息](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC3ec.png)

Comment: Do you want to replace 2019.1 with 2022.2.3? Or do you want to upgrade existing 2019.1 to 2022.2.3? Have you read the [installation guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/installation-guide.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the javaagent configuration from .vmoptions file should help.
Please see: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/zh-cn/articles/360014727620